# Remove scroll bars on div in IE?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the property:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

On IE11 (havent tested other versions of IE yet) the div has a vertical grey scroll bar. Is there a way to remove this? But still maintain the overflow scroll?

I searched SO for an answer but only could find one relating to the body scroll bars and not a div.

Comment: There's no difference between "body scrollbars" and "div scrollbars"; they are the same thing. By the way, this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Answer (score 2):

Use `auto` property

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

`scroll` will always add scrollbar whether content is overflown or not. Using auto will show the scrollbar only when content is overflown.

[**MDN Doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Values)